# Nginx 404 error with jpg files

Tags: nginx

I'm completely confused with getting 404 error, though everything seems be alright.

I need to give access to several files to an external web-site - 1 swf and several jpgs.

location directive works perfectly for an swf:

```
location /test.swf {
    root /www/test/static/swf;
}
```

And it perfectly opens with example.com/test.swf

And then some magic happens with jpg files. I always get 404 error whatever I do. I've tried:

```
location /img {
    root /www/test/static/img;
}
```

It gives 404 when i try to access jpg files with example.com/img/img1.jpg

I've even tried the same way as it works for swf:

```
location /img1.jpg {
    root /www/test/static/img;
}
```

And again 404 on `example.com/img1.jpg`

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I am not an expert in nginx, but have you tried with `location /img/`?

Comment: Yep. I've tried all the ways:  location /img {
    root /www/test/static/img;
   }  location /img/ {
    root /www/test/static/img;
   } location /img/ {
    root /www/test/static/img/;
   } location /img {
    root /www/test/static/img/;
   }

Comment: What are the permission on the file and what system do you use to serve with nginx ?

Comment: File and folder permissions are all 755. I use Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Thereis error.log file. Check it

Comment: Thanks for the tip with error.log. It cleared a bit that nginx tried to look for a file in another directory.